# Problem with getting an image and put in a jframe

Tags: java, image

actually I want to make a snake in java, and i'm at the point where i have to put images in my frame for the snake body. I search for solutions, but none of them worked, i tried jlabel, or just an image, and it does exactly the same thing. After searching for some github pages, i found out that i've got a problem somewhere else, because i've the same code for images.

here's my code :

````java
private ImageIcon upMouth;
    private ImageIcon downMouth;
    private ImageIcon leftMouth;
    private ImageIcon rightMouth;

    private ImageIcon body;
    private ImageIcon dot;

    private int[] lensnakeX = new int[750];
    private int[] lensnakeY = new int[750];

    private int moves = 0;

    private int length = 3;

    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean right = false;

    private Timer t;
    private int delay = 140;

    public Content(){
        initGame();
    }

    public void initGame(){
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        t = new Timer(delay, this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        doDrawing(g);
    }

    public void doDrawing(@NotNull Graphics g){
        if(moves == 0){
            lensnakeX[2] = 50;
            lensnakeX[1] = 75;
            lensnakeX[0] = 100;

            lensnakeY[2] = 100;
            lensnakeY[1] = 100;
            lensnakeY[0] = 100;
        }

        //title
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(24,10, 851, 55);

        Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 60);
        g2d.setFont(f);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("Snake", 375, 55);

        //gameplay
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(24, 74, 851, 600);

        //background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(25, 75, 850, 575);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(i == 0 && right){
                rightMouth = new ImageIcon("src/resources/right.png");
                rightMouth.paintIcon(this, g, lensnakeX[i], lensnakeY[i]);
            }
            if(i == 0 && left){
                leftMouth = new ImageIcon("src/resources/left.png");
                leftMouth.paintIcon(this, g, lensnakeX[i], lensnakeY[i]);
            }
            if(i == 0 && up){
                upMouth = new ImageIcon("src/resources/up.png");
                upMouth.paintIcon(this, g, lensnakeX[i], lensnakeY[i]);
            }
            if(i == 0 && down){
                downMouth = new ImageIcon("src/resources/down.png");
                Image image = downMouth.getImage();
                downMouth.paintIcon(this, g, lensnakeX[i], lensnakeY[i]);
            }

            if(i != 0){
                body = new ImageIcon("src/resources/body.png");
                body.paintIcon(this, g, lensnakeX[i], lensnakeY[i]);
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
    }```

The expected result is a snake with 3 parts (1 head and 2 parts for the body), but i've only got a jframe with a black rect, and a white rect for the title with "Snake" in it. Thank you for taking time to answer.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait so you wrote all this before you tested if one image is appearing? can you give me a working example with the main function so we can test this?

Here is a simple code to view an image i created:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestGround extends JPanel {

    private Image img;
    ImageIcon ii ;


    public TestGround(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);

        // load the image in the constructor:
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("src/resources/picon.png");
        img = ii.getImage();       
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       
        doDrawing(g);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }


    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {    
         //drawing a grid of lines
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         // draw the image:
         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestGround());
        frame.setTitle("Show Image");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);       
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Actually, i've sent the code to a friend, he tested it, and it works. So there's a problem but not with my code, and i don't know where because images are found (debug) but they aren't appearing on the frame

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of the java tool kit? i don't know what your friend has that you don't ^^"